# Wordpress matching page title to pull up tagged stories

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am trying to create a custom page template in wordpress, where if the title=Cars, it will pull up the latest stories related to Cars.

This is the line I need help with,

```
<div class="topposts">
        <?php query_posts('tag=$page_title&showposts=3'); ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li>
            <?php woo_get_image('image','165','115','thumbnail',90,$post->ID,'img'); ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php echo excerpt(20); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's your question? Is there a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Basic PHP syntax: `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** interpolate variables:

```
    <?php query_posts('tag=$page_title&showposts=3'); ?>
                      ^---------------------------^---
```

you're telling WP to look for tags that have the literal characters `$`, `p`, `a`, etc...

Try

```
    <?php query_posts("tag=$page_title&showposts=3"); ?>
                      ^---------------------------^--
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the single quotes in your query with double quotes.

The below code should work

```
<div class="topposts">
    <?php query_posts("tag=$page_title&showposts=3"); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <?php woo_get_image('image','165','115','thumbnail',90,$post->ID,'img'); ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php echo excerpt(20); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```